# load content by ajax when scroll reach to bottom

Tags: javascript, ajax

i am so tired of this and i found no solution for this until now.here is my code

```
$("#submit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()  
    var loading = "<img src='/zojfa/images/loading.gif' alt='Loading...' />";
    var scrolltop=$('#scrollbox').attr('scrollTop');
    var scrollheight=$('#scrollbox').attr('scrollHeight');
    var windowheight=$('#scrollbox').attr('clientHeight');
    var post = $(this).attr("name") + "=" + $(this).val();
    var form_data = $('#search_form').serialize() + "&" + post;

    var scrolloffset=20;
    $('#search').html(loading);
    $.post("dosearch.php",form_data,function(newitems) {
        $('#content').append(newitems);
            });
    $('#scrollbox').scroll(function(){
    if(scrolltop>=(scrollheight-(windowheight+scrolloffset))){
        form_data = form_data + "&size=" + $("#content > div").size();
    setTimeout($.post("dosearch.php",form_data,function(newitems) {
        $('#content').append(newitems);
            }),5000);
    }
    });     
        });

});
```

when i post form data this form data will serialize() and send to dosearch.php.

the function work well when i click on submit button function will execute and give me the result set which is line 11 of this script.

then i will listen to scroll event, when scroll event will happen i'll count the div's inside my content div to know how many div i have loaded until now and send this number to dosearch to get more result

SELECT something FROM table WHERE someid=some another id LIMIT $number(which i get from counting divs.. is there another solution?maybe set id for divs?is this solution that i use good enough?),6

now where is my problem.i check posted data by firebug

and when i reach the bottom of this div many ajax request fire up.and shows many posted size with diffrent value like this in firebug console

```
size=6
size=12
size=12
```

i thought about settimeout maybe fix my script but gain no success in this.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

This links can help you to get the result.
[Click here for demo](http://demo.webdeveloperplus.com/dynamic-scrollbox/)

[This is how will work](http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/create-a-dynamic-scrolling-content-box-using-ajax/)

Comment: i used this example to reach this situation...how should i get form data in this example?how should i use $("#submit").click(function(e){